# Как правильно структурировать функциональный код на python

Tags: python, функции

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно структурировать функциональный код на python, без создания классов.

```
def родитель_0():
    дочерняя_a()
    дочерняя_b()

def родитель_1():
    дочерняя_c()
    дочерняя_d()

def main_function():
    родитель_0()
    родитель_1()
```

Функция должна быть объявлена заранее,
но в какой последовательности расположить function_0 и function_1? и как
расположить их дочерние функции a,b,c,d? Все сверху пред родительскими функциями или каждую
функцию расположить пред своим родителем?

Comment: Нет разницы как

Comment: pep никакие это не регламентируют?

Answer (score 1):

Это не имеет значения, если функции друг друга видят, значит все ок.

Comment: Ваш подход практичный, но не стильный. Если бы мы писали переменные юникодом или названия классов без CamelCase, даже можно увеличить длину строки больше 80 символов - тоже бы всё работало, может быть какой-то PEP регламентирует это? Что бы у всех был единообразный стиль. На всё у них есть советы, а на такой нет?